# PHP Download image and redirect external url

Tags: php, redirect, force-download

I want to download image and redirect to specific external url in PHP.

I have this code,

```
$file_name = '1.png';
  // make sure it's a file before doing anything!
  if( !is_file($file_name) )
    exit();
  // required for IE
  if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression'))
    ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');
  // get the file mime type using the file extension
  switch(strtolower(substr(strrchr($file_name,'.'),1)))
  {
    case 'pdf': $mime = 'application/pdf'; break;
    case 'zip': $mime = 'application/zip'; break;
    case 'jpeg':
    case 'jpg': $mime = 'image/jpg'; break;
    case 'png': $mime = 'image/png'; break;
    default: exit();
  }
  header('Pragma: public');     // required
  header('Expires: 0');     // no cache
  header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
  header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate ('D, d M Y H:i:s', filemtime ($file_name)).' GMT');
  header('Cache-Control: private',false);
  header('Content-Type: '.$mime);
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file_name).'"');
  header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
  header('Content-Length: '.filesize($file_name));  // provide file size
  header('Connection: close');
  readfile($file_name);     // push it out

  header('Location: http://google.com');
```

But, there are no redirection after download.

How can i solve this situation, thanks for your helps & advices.

Comment: @miken32 can you implement this solution to my code ?

Answer (score 0):

If you download the file which means you have already received the response(Header already send to the client).

There is no way in PHP to set custom header and then have a redirect.

What you can do is have an Ajax call from client side to download the image and then another Ajax call to redirect page.

Comment: Downloading is not start when i get ajax request, but i can get response image file in network tab on chrome devtools.

Comment: You might have to play some trick over here.Create dynalic <a> tag with the image content then click it by javascript.Try this https://nehalist.io/downloading-files-from-post-requests/